# mysql query and performance

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, performance

I would like to know the impact on performance if I run this query in the following conditions.

Query:

```
select   `players`.*, count(`clicks`.`id`) as `clicks_count` 
from     `players` left join `clicks` on `clicks`.`player_id` = `players`.`id`
group by `players`.`id`
order by `clicks_count` desc 
limit    1
```

Conditions:

1. In the clicks table I expect to get
   insert 1000 times in a 1 minute
2. The clicks table will contain more
   then 1,000,000 rows
3. The players table will contain
   10,000 rows
4. The players table get inserted into every 5
   minutes

I would like to know what to expect performance-wise if I run the query 1000 times in 1 minute.

Thanks

Comment: Impossible to tell without knowing a lot of things about your server and setup. Why not simply try out?

Comment: @Yonathan, the query as such looks fine, don't worry about performance until you actually hit slowness, than come back and ask a question about it with some details.  *"Premature optimization is the root of all evil"* -- Donald Knuth.

Comment: ok, thanks. same as always `Trial and error`!

Comment: If things get slow, `EXPLAIN` can sometimes give you clues as to how your query is being done. Here's a friendly tree based version: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2007/07/29/introducing-mysql-visual-explain/

Comment: Make sure to use transactions. There is a big difference between 1000 *INSERTS* per second and 1000 *COMMITS* per second (good luck!). Also decide which is more important -- inserts or queries. Indexes will speed up queries (if covering correctly) but require more work to maintain. Extra indexes *may* actually hurt both query (if they muck up the plan) and insert performance.

Comment: thanks all for the greatest tips!!!! everyone here help me so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That query will *never* run in milliseconds with any meaningful amounts of data in your tables. It'll run two full table scans, join the two together, aggregate the mess, and fetch the top row from that.

Use a trigger to store the total in the players, and index that field. You'll then be able to avoid the join altogether:

```
select p.* from players p order by clicks_count desc limit 1
```

Comment: i like the idea with the trigger, can you please show me how to declare one for my situation. i am not familiar with triggers

Comment: and what about just adding to the players table column with clicks_count and every click just adding 1 is it will be beter then a trigger?

Comment: yes thats exactly what Denis wrote, add that column and update it by adding 1 for every click either by a trigger or just separate update query. If you don't need to store additional info about a click like a date, who clicked or sth like that, you can even drop clicks table and just update clicks_counter in players.

Comment: @Denis when you write _That query will never run in milliseconds_ so how worse it could get?

Comment: @yonathan: with millions and billions of rows, it will run into the minutes, hours and days.

Comment: sound scary, how facebook, and google, yahoo handling with the database? it's wrok for them preety fast

Comment: they cache the values, like you're being suggested to do. and they use table stats.

Answer (score 0):

First & foremost, you should worry about your schema if you want decent performance with that number of records and frequent writes; i.e. proper indexes and constraints must be created if not already in place.

Next, the query itself, select the minimum number of fields needed (so if you do not need ALL players field, avoid using "players.*").

Personal pref, I'd restructure tables (e.g. playerID in place of id) and query like so:

```
SELECT p.*, COUNT(c.id) as clicks_count
FROM players p
JOIN clicks c USING(playerID)
GROUP BY p.playerID
ORDER BY clicks_count desc 
LIMIT 1
```

Again, see if you really need ALL player table fields; if not, omit "p.*" and replace with p.foo, p.bar, etc.

Comment: thanks for the tip. but i like to know if this situation is normal and it colud be handled and how shold i handle it

Comment: well, you are dealing with a large record set and frequent writes -- just see how it goes (in production), lol, nice suggestion ;--) Plan ahead I say (so create PK on playerID in players table and add FK on playerID in clicks table; then select minimum fields necessary; have your read queries set to read only; allocate sufficient cpu cycles and memory to handle the load, determined by load testing prior to putting anything in production)

Comment: fair enough, of course, we're all relatively in the dark as to his situation. @denis has it nailed performance-wise querying against a single table